# How to handle session timeout during json calls in asp.net mvc3 web application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In our project we make a lot of json callbacks for various operations. I will give you an example of one such ajax call below

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../Controller1/Method1',
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'Id': '" + Id "'}",
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#div').html(result);
    }, error: function (s) {
        ShowAlert(s.responseText);
    }
});
```

Now when the session is timed out and if we are making a json ajax callback,then it is not redirecting to the login page properly ,
so how to handle session timeout during json ajax callback and if the session is expired and a ajax callback is made it should redirect me to the login page.

How to achieve this?. Any help(code samples,useful links) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you can get back a specific error message, why can't you simply do a `window.location = <yourLoginUrl>;`?

Comment: if session is timed out and a ajax callback is made, then i wan my login page to rendered.

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication? If so, the default behavior of an unauthenticated request send to a page with an authorize attribute would be to issue a redirect to the login page. The issue here is your AJAX call wont know you got redirected and the content would be the login page.  It would be adviseable to modify your MVC project to return a HTTP 401 and let your AJAX calls eat the 401 and show some login box.

Comment: Hi nick thanks for the reply from your answer "It would be advisable to modify your MVC project to return a HTTP 401" how to achieve this? any links or samples for achieving the same.

Answer (score 2):

When ajax call is made and session is timeout the return with specific
error message, now if responce is come with specific error message then simply do a window.location =

Answer (score 0):

is 12030 a http response? why not return or throw (depending on if you're in a web-api or normal controller):

return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

then in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  //.........
  statusCode: {
      408: function () {
          console.log('Call timed out');
      }
  }
});
```

perhaps